# When Google Chrome spawns a new process?

Tags: multithreading, performance, google-chrome, process, ipc

When I see the task manager of Google's Chrome I could see few (each) tabs run under individual process and group of tabs run under a single process. Out of curiosity, I searched to know why it runs as multiple process instead of multiple threads. And one thing which brought to my attention is when it runs as a single process and spawns multiple threads there could be few limitations/drawbacks like,

1) Limitation on number of threads that could be created

2) When a single tab becomes unresponsive the entire application would be come useless and we have to quit chrome and restart it due to some misbehaving site.

A few mentioned that Chrome uses single process per domain, but here it doesn't seem to be true.

[image]

I'm still not clear on,

1) When Chrome decides to spawn a new process?

2) What are the other advantage of running individual tabs under separate process?

3) How cookies are shared between tabs when each of them run under different process? Is this happening via interprocess communication? If yes, will it be too costly? And will it impact the other tab's (ie' the web page) performance?

Answer (score 0):

After asking this question, I came to see this article ([Multi Process Architecture of Chromium](https://blog.chromium.org/2008/09/multi-process-architecture.html)) and it answered my question (1).

> When Chrome decides to spawn a new process?

Once Google Chrome has created its browser process, it will generally create one renderer process for each instance of a web site you visit.  This approach aims to keep pages from different web sites isolated from each other.

You can think of this as using a different process for each tab in the browser, but allowing two tabs to share a process if they are related to each other and are showing the same site.  For example, if one tab opens another tab using JavaScript, or if you open a link to the same site in a new tab, the tabs will share a renderer process.  This lets the pages in these tabs communicate via JavaScript and share cached objects.  Conversely, if you type the URL of a different site into the location bar of a tab, they will swap in a new renderer process for the tab.

They place a limit on the number of renderer processes that they create (as 20 in most cases).  Once they hit this limit, they'll start re-using the existing renderer processes for new tabs.

> What are the advantage of running tabs under different process?

Google Chrome takes advantage of these properties and puts web apps and plug-ins in separate processes from the browser itself.  This means that a rendering engine crash in one web app won't affect the browser or other web apps.  It means the OS can run web apps in parallel to increase their responsiveness, and it means the browser itself won't lock up if a particular web app or plug-in stops responding.  It also means they can run the rendering engine processes in a restrictive sandbox that helps limit the damage if an exploit does occur.

Interestingly, using multiple processes means Google Chrome can have its own Task Manager (shown below), which you can get to by right clicking on the browser's title bar.  This Task Manager lets you track resource usage for each web app and plug-in, rather than for the entire browser.  It also lets you kill any web apps or plug-ins that have stopped responding, without having to restart the entire browser.